# How do I get rid of Windows File Explorer left-pane entries

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On my left pane on Windows File Explorer, I have a bunch of entries that I don't care for:

[image]

How do I get rid of them? Some where added by Adobe (red), other's came with Windows itself but I don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the folders under **This PC**, you can copy & paste the following into an *Admin* **PowerShell** window:

```
$FD = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions'
gci $FD |
 ?{(gp $_.PSPath).Name -match 'Local (Music|Pictures|Video)|3D'} | %{
    $PropBag = Join-Path $_.PSPath 'PropertyBag'
    If ( !( Test-Path $PropBag )) {
        New-Item $PropBag | Out-Null
    }
    $Splat = @{
        Path  = $PropBag
        Name  = 'ThisPCPolicy'
        Value = 'Hide'
    }
    Set-ItemProperty  @Splat
}
```

I'm not familiar with **Creative Cloud Files**, but you should be able to locate it in the registry under either:
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`
or
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`
as a GUID-named subkey similar to these. Delete the one you determine to be Creative Cloud.
[image]